# Java wait for FileChooser

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way how I can pause my main-function while there is a JFrame with a filechooser. The User should choose his directory and then a file should be created dynamically.

Here is a part of the code

```
        DirectoryChooser selectPath = new DirectoryChooser();   //Filechooser for Path 
        String sourcePath = selectPath.getSourcePath();

        //Here the programm should take a break to wait for the sourcePath

        try 
        {                                                                               
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(sourcePath+"/Result.txt");   //Create File
            BufferedWriter ausgabe = new BufferedWriter(fw);

             //*** More code ***
```

The filechooser dialog is created in a sperate class and you can get the path-string with the `getSourcePath()` method

Comment: Don't you open it the dialog somewhere?

Comment: do you need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921142/use-a-thread-to-wait-until-the-user-has-picked-a-file#answer-26921697)?

Comment: Thank you @JackWhiteIII ! Helped me a lot. Very good and easy solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy is approach is to do something like this. Your codes will be executed only when a file is selected.

```
javax.swing.JFileChooser chooser = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
File yourFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
if(yourFile!=null)  //Check if user selected a file
{
    //write your codes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `showDialog()` method (or whatever the corresponding DirectoryChooser method is called) to show the dialog to the user. If you're referring to the DirectoryChooser class in the JavaFX library you can call `showDialog(Window owner)` to make the dialog block IO to the owner window as well.